# Cannot connect to openvpn server on windows but works fine on android

Tags: windows-10, openvpn, ubuntu-server

I have set up an openvpn server on Ubuntu server 16.04lts using DigitalOcean's guide and have no issues connecting on my android phone but when I try to connect from my laptop I get the error:

> `--up script fails with '/etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf' : No such process (errno=3)`

I've tried the same ovpn file I used on my phone and tried it when I made another and the same error occurred. I've also tried it when my laptop was not on the same network as the server incase that was the issue but the same error occurs.

Comment: Try posting some more info about your setup, including relevant parts of your config file. `/etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf` is a unix-style path which you shouldn't see on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I found that one of the steps that DigitalOcean said to do was to add the script that is causing the issue into the config file, and that Android must ignore it while on windows it causes an error. I commented it out on my laptop and it works fine now.